# Option to save project files for later use in Dreamweaver?

Tags: dreamweaver

Does anyone know of an extension or other way to allow me to save a set of files in a project for later use?

Example: 
 - Working on site A, opened html files A1-A15 (15 files)

- Received a request to work on site B, new files (number unimportant).
- I would like DW to remember that I was working on files A1-A15.
- Close the site A files and focus on just files from site B.
- Complete site B work.
- Reopen site A files altogether.

Suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Something similar to the old save sessions plugin for firefox that would save your open tabs and let you name that session to re-open those tabs at a later date. But in DW save the opened files your working on?

Answer (score 1):

What I always do, is save all the files from one project in it's own folder, then to open them all again, hit "CTRL+A" to select all the files in the folder, then "[enter]" to open them all at the same time in Dreamweaver. This DEPENDS on the "default program" for opening files of that type. (I believe the last file you select if you do "CTRL+[click]" for selecting only a few files, is the first one to be opened. But of course, you can re-order the tabs by drag and drop.

If your computer has enough horsepower, you could open multiple instances of Dreamweaver and keep it minimized as well.

Third and almost as important: If your index page has "includes" (PHP) or links to other pages like a stylesheet, they will automatically be sub-tabbed under the main page. See the following image:

[image: sub-tabs for included files]

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can do is reopen documents on startup.

Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2014

Edit > Preferences > General > Reopen documents on startup.

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest I could find

http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&extid=193712